# What will happen if the server opens connection to port but the Client didn't send any thing? (Java Server Socket)

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm using java socket to transfer data from Client Side to my Server, User has to click a button to open a connection with a specific port and client had to run executable jar file to send the data to the opened port but in some cases user click the button and then close the browser tab for some reason ! 
When he tries to click the button again it gives

> Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Is there any way to get over this?!

Is it possible to kill any process on a port before using it ?

My server side class code in case if anyone need to check :

```
class Server {
private Socket socket = null;
private ServerSocket server = null;
private DataInputStream in = null;

public Server(Integer port) throws Exception {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        JSFUtils.addFacesInformationMessage("Waiting for a Data...");
        socket = server.accept();
        JSFUtils.addFacesInformationMessage("Done");
        in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line = in.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Data Scaned >> " + line);
    } catch (Exception i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close connection
        if (socket != null)
            socket.close();
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Server side socket can handle multiple connections on same port. Check your code or post it here.

Comment: @MladenSavić i have added the code in case you needed to check

Comment: The problem with your code is that server creates an instance, and wait to accept the client in constructor. First in constructor only  create an instance. Dont write whole cycle in constructor. Create another method that will do following : https://pastebin.com/pdCanTQe

Comment: Thanks for the Tip .. but actually it didn't answer my question .. i asked how to cancel / kill the waiting on the server side after calling "server.accept();", btw i don't want threading user cant continue on the server unless he run the jar.

Comment: My apologies, didn't read the question fully i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i could get over this issue by using `server.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);` you can set the time out with the time you want in ms .. after the specified time runs out with out a client side answer it will raise "SocketTimeoutException" and user can re-click the button on server side again you can implement this logic in something like that

```
            try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            server.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);
            socket = server.accept();
            JSFUtils.addFacesInformationMessage("Scan Completed Successfully");
            // takes input from the client socket
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line = in.readUTF();
        } catch (Exception i) {
            if (i instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
                JSFUtils.addFacesErrorMessage("Scan Timeout, Please click Scan again!");
            else
                i.printStackTrace();
        }
```